# Does BigQuery allow mulitple-table joins with a SQL `with` clause?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, left-join, with-clause

Does BigQuery allow mulitple-table joins with a SQL `with` clause?

Example:

```
WITH t1 as (select tab1, tab2 from t1 group by 1,2), 
t2 as ( select tab1, tab2, tab3, from t2 group by 1,2,3)
t3 as ( select tab1, tab2, from t3 group by 1,2,3)
```

I can make the query below work by repeating the same query multiple times, but do not want to, and want to leverage it with `with as`:

```
SELECT a.tab1, a.tab2, b.tab1, b. tab3, c.tab1, c.tab2
FROM  t1 a
LEFT JOIN t2 b
ON a.tabl = b.tab1 and a.tab2 = b.tab3
LEFT JOIN t3 c
ON a.tab1 = c.tab1

SELECT a.tab1, a.tab2, b.tab1, b. tab3, c.tab1, c.tab2
FROM  t1 a
LEFT JOIN t2 b
ON a.tabl = b.tab1 and a.tab2 = b.tab3
LEFT JOIN t3 c
ON a.tab1 = c.tab1
```

Comment: So what happened when you tried using these CTEs in BigQuery? What is the actual issue you are facing?

Comment: Is yes or no the answer you really want? What is the point of giving that code? What are you trying to do & how are you stuck doing it? [ask] [Help] [mre]

Comment: GROUP BY but no aggregate functions? Do you simply want SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: A WITH clause is local for a query. You can create views instead. (But I'm not sure that's the solution in this specific case.)

Comment: Hi @solomonpaul, Does using [views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views) resolve your issue?